# What are Erlang Alternatives?

Tags: java, c++, erlang, message, fsm

What are the closest framework to Erlang for other programming languages like Java, C++ especially for

1. Embedded linux application
2. The framework support a close flavor of the FSM model of Erlang in addition to other main features of Erlang so for instance Node.js is really not a great option for such requirement I gather

Comment: This question has been closed, so I can't provide an official answer. But, maybe the QP/C++ active object (actor) framework would fit the bill. QP/C++ runs very well on Linux (with P-threads). The QP framework also provides strong support for hierarchical state machines (UML Statecharts) to model the behavior of the event-driven active objects. The framework provides an easy way to code HSMs manually in highly readable code, but you can also use the free QM modeling tool to draw statecharts and generate the QP code automatically. See http://www.state-machine.com for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, [Akka](http://akka.io/docs/) is the state of the art actor technology.

It has Erlang-like [become/unbecome](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#actor-hotswap) method for switching the current processor function, but also has a more idiomatic [FSM module](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html). There are also some news about [Akka running on ARM Linux](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/06/01/low-power-arm-kernel-and-akka/) devices.

Comment: As far as I know, Akka is the nearest you will find across mainstream technologies.

Comment: I did not know about this. How mature is Akka? Is it ready for prime-time? Do you know anybody using it in production? How does it compare to Erlang?

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-fit-for-a-concurrent-app-Scala+Akka-or-Erlang

Comment: @ron Erlang runs on Arm as well, I am running it on a Raspberry Pi making a little robot run.

Comment: iCode: Slide 25 of this presentation lists a few http://www.slideshare.net/jboner/introducing-akka

Answer (score 1):

1. Cloud Haskell
2. Any language + RabbitMQ/ZeroMQ

Comment: Point number 2 makes no sense.

Comment: Can you explain more about your point 2?

Comment: @ViktorKlang Considering that the strong point for Erlang is the actor model embedded in it's core language features, and that the actor model is basically some processes runing independently and passing along messages to other processes (actors). These concepts can be  replicated easly with any language + a MOM (messaging oriented middleware). That's the answer for no. 2. If there was any language with OOP features + actor model, I would switch right away (until then actor model framewor + oop language > erlang)

Comment: m late in party. Can anybody please explain how does problem of scaling will be solved with RabbitMa/ZeroMQ ?